# Nested For loop eternally running?

Tags: c#, for-loop, nested

I'm having a little trouble figuring out a nested for loop here. Here's the problem:

> 3. The population of Ireland is 4.8 million and growing at a rate of 7% per year. Write a program to determine and display the population
>      in 10 years time. Your program should also display a count of the
>      number of years that the population is predicted to exceed 5 million.

And here's what I've coded so far:

```
    double pop = 4.8;
    int years = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        pop += (pop / 100) * 7;

        for (int j = 0; pop >5; j++)
        {
            years += j;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Pop in year 2030 is " + Math.Round(pop, 2) + " million and the population will be over 5 million for " + years + " years.");
}
```

Now to be clear, I need the sum of the years in which population exceeds 5(million) (the answer is 10) and I must only use for loops to solve this problem. I'm thinking the answer is a nested for loop, but have tried and tried with no success.

Can anyone help me on where I've screwed this up?

Comment: Please post the question, not a link to a screenshot of it.

Comment: The inner for loop is infinite ("eternal") because `pop` isnt ever changed inside it.  Always post information critical to the question *in* the question, not as a link.  Make it easy for people to help you and for the question to have some value for future users.

Comment: Get a piece of paper and a pen (or pencil) and a calculator and step through your code. When `i` equals 0 (zero), `pop = ?`. When `i` equals 1 (one), `pop = ?` and so on. After that you simply need to count the number of times `pop` exceeds 5, right? By the way, `pop * 0.07` also calculates 7% of `pop`.

Comment: One of the first and most important skills to learn in programming is [how to debug](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your inner loop.

```
    for (int j = 0; pop >5; j++)
    {
        years += j;
    }
```

Your condition being `pop > 5`, you need `pop` to shrink if you ever want to exit the loop.  But the body of the loop never alters `pop`, so if it's greater than 5, you'll loop forever.

The problem definition suggests that you don't need an inner loop at all.  Just check `pop`, and if it's greater than 5, increment `years`.

```
    if (pop > 5)
    {
         ++years;
    }
```

If you're really under such an insane restriction that you can't use `if`, you could do something boneheaded like create a `for` loop that only runs once if your other condition is right.

```
    for (int j = 0; j < 1 && pop > 5; ++j)
    {
        ++years;
    }
```

but no sane person does this.

Comment: The if statement solution is clearly the right thing to do in this situation, unfortunately the exercise needs only for loops to solve, which has be baffled! Thank you for your help though

Comment: @BenLawlor: Updated.  It's a very odd restriction, but certainly not impossible. :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to clearer variable names in my opinion. Of course, don't go to far with that, but IMO `population` will be better than just `pop`.

Furhter, you could use `Dictionary` to store years alongside with preidcted population.

Also, write comments to better see what's going on :)

With this suggestions, I would code this like below:

```
double population = 4.8;
int currentYear = 2020;
Dictionary<int, double> predictions = new Dictionary<int, double>();
// Adding current state
predictions.Add(currentYear, population);

// I changed bounds of a loop to handle years in more comfortable way :)
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
  population *= 1.07;
  predictions.Add(currentYear + i, population);
}
```

Now you have data in `Dictionary` that looks like this:

```
2020  4.8
2021  ...
2022  ...
...   ...
```

Now you can get all years, where population was over 5 million easily with `predictions.Where(kvp => kvp.Value > 5)`.

Answer (score 0):

If I well understand your question.
Technically if you add 7% each year your program should look like this

```
bool passed = true;
double pop = 4.8;
int year = 0;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
 pop *= 1.07;
if (pop > 5 && passed)
{
 year = i;
 passed = false;
}
}
```